# Can't get management instance of graph

Tags: gremlin, gremlin-server

I connect to gremlin server from gremlin console:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server config/connect_config.yaml
```

I can execute queries like:

```
:> graph.getGraphName()
:> g.V().count().next()
:> g.V().drop().iterate()
:> g.V().values('LOL')
```

and many others. g - GraphTraversalSource, graph - StandardJanusGraph.
I need to configure schema of graph:

```
:> mg = graph.openManagenet()
```

but when i try to execute this query, i get exception:

```
gremlin> :> mngmt = graph.openManagement()
Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: Class is not registered: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.class);. Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.plugin.RemoteException: Server could not serialize the result requested. Server error - Error during serialization: Class is not registered: org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem
Note: To register this class use: kryo.register(org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.management.ManagementSystem.class);. Note that the class must be serializable by the client and server for proper operation.
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.groovy.plugin.DriverRemoteAcceptor.submit(DriverRemoteAcceptor.java:186)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.commands.SubmitCommand.execute(SubmitCommand.groovy:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.execute(Shell.groovy:104)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.super$2$execute(Groovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.executeCommand(Groovysh.groovy:273)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Groovysh.execute(Groovysh.groovy:164)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.super$3$execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor14.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.GremlinGroovysh.execute(GremlinGroovysh.groovy:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Shell.leftShift(Shell.groovy:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.work(ShellRunner.groovy:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor35.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.work(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:130)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.ShellRunner.run(ShellRunner.groovy:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.super$2$run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuperN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:145)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnSuper0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:165)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.InteractiveShellRunner.run(InteractiveShellRunner.groovy:89)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.<init>(Console.groovy:169)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:236)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.console.Console.main(Console.groovy:481)
```

Can somebody say me what i must do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that the `ManagementSystem` is serializable so that's why you are getting that error. There are at least two ways to sort it out. First, you didn't post what is in your `config/connect_config.yaml` but I assume it is not using this sort of configuration option for the serializer:

```
hosts: [localhost]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

By using the `serializeResultToString` option (and assuming that serializer is configured in Gremlin Server in its configuration) you tell Gremlin Server to take any result you get and call `toString()` on it before it is returned. In that way, you never get serialization errors.

But, the downside is that you only get `String` values back. Generally speaking, I would think that is ok for most Gremlin Console interactions (especially administrative ones like the one you are trying to execute with the `ManagementSystem` API. So, if you wanted to continue using your current configuration which tries to serialize actual "objects" you just need to be sure your scripts only return data that is serializable so instead of:

```
:> mg = graph.openManagement()
```

do

```
:> mg = graph.openManagement();[]
```

which doesn't return `mg`, but rather an empty list.

Comment: Thanks!!! Can you give reference to info, where contains information about configs and other of janusgraph, gremlinserver and gremlin-console?

Comment: Gremlin Server configuration is here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_configuring_2 and Remote Gremlin Console is here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-via-console and driver connectivity related to the remote console is here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_connecting